# How Content-Assist (dot Ctrl+space) works in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

What Java concept does the Content-Assist uses for auto completion and suggestions in eclipse.

Comment: Way too broad. In essence, this has nothing to do with Java. The IDE basically knows "all symbols" that might be used; and it knows for example that "someObject." requires to check the class of someObject; to see which methods are available to be called. This is more of a very **complex** compiler construction question.

Comment: Eclipse uses the information from the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) as the basis for this.